# Disable IntelliJ code completion for Groovy comments

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is doing code completion while I'm editing a comment. The Groovy file looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
    // 
    def someMethod() {
    }
}
```

When I start typing text on the comment line above `someMethod()`, IntelliJ thinks I'm entering a class name and thus brings up code completion.

[image]

Is there a way to disable this? It should be obvious to IntelliJ that I'm in a comment.

I'm using IntelliJ 10.5.4 to edit a Groovy file.

**Follow-up**: I tried this with Java and IntelliJ does not perform code completion within a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a bug which also affects the latest IDEA version, [submitted to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-79597), please vote.